# What makes one question constructive and a similar one not constructive?

Tags: support, not-constructive

I realized I was taking a bit of a gamble when I asked [Why did you stop using JSF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6861599/why-did-you-stop-using-jsf), but as I say in the question, it's very similar to [Why did you stop using Tapestry?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1303438/why-did-you-stop-using-tapestry). I don't understand why mine is closed as not constructive, when the question I based mine on is not. The wording is almost identical.

Comment: Your question was asked an hour ago. The Tapestry question was asked two years ago. The rules have changed since then. The Tapestry question would be closed if it were asked today. It _should_ be closed now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Absolutely nothing.  The Tapestry question is now closed.

Comment: It seems absurd to me to mark the original as not constructive when it is so helpful and full of useful information and links. But I'd rather have consistency I guess. Thanks for taking a minute to help me out with this.

Comment: @Daniel: I agree that the short description of "not constructive" is a bit off, but the longer description `"This question is not a good fit to our Q&A format. We expect answers to generally involve facts, references, or specific expertise; this question will likely solicit opinion, debate, arguments, polling, or extended discussion."` is right on.